# How large a sample from the population is required?

Tags: sampling

I have a question phrased in non-scientific language, I'm sorry but it's the best I could do.

I have a list of all addresses in Australia that contains approximately 10 million records, each with a unique identifier.

Every day I have customers entering address information on my website. I have three different ways to match this new address information with the unique id's but none are 100% accurate. I want to test which one is most accurate and then select the highest performing one. So I am going to run each on the same sample of new addresses and then compare the outputs manually to the population file.

How I could calculate how large to make the sample if I want to be very sure (say, 95% sure) that I am selecting the most accurate method of matching those addresses?

Comment: We're going to need some data. How many distinct customers (on average) insert new addresses per day? How many addresses are added per day (on average)? How many addresses are unique (on average)? Are there differences in the customers based on the day of week/week/month?

Comment: You will need a larger sample if the three success rates are actually 90%, 91%, 92% than if they are 50%, 80%, 99%.